# Spring-data-aerospike `findAll(ids)` returns NULLs in result

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, repository-pattern, aerospike

`Spring-data-aerospike` method `findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)` returns list with `NULL`s for non-existing entities.

In case some of entities **do** exist and some of them **do not** exist - the result would be an `Iterable` with both `NULL`s and existing entities combined:  *[entity1, null, entity2, null]*.

It's not useful during the processing of results of `findAll(Iterable<ID> ids)`, because of `NPE`s.

After looking at source code I found the following method in the class `org.springframework.data.aerospike.core.AerospikeTemplate`:

```
@Override
public  <T> List<T> findByIDs(Iterable<Serializable> IDs, Class<T> type){
    AerospikePersistentEntity<?> entity = mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(type);
    List<Key> kList = new ArrayList<Key>();
    IDs.forEach(id -> kList.add(new Key(this.namespace, entity.getSetName(), id.toString())));
    Record[] rs = this.client.get(null, kList.toArray(new Key[kList.size()]));
    final List<T> tList = new ArrayList<T>();
    for(int i=0; i < rs.length; i++)
        tList.add(mapToEntity(kList.get(i), type, rs[i])); // <--- mapToEntity here may return NULL (is it a bug or by design?)
    return tList;
}
```

Thus, the question is:

1. Is this normal behaviour according to design?
2. Shouldn't it be something like: `if(entity != null) tList.add(entity);` instead?

---

Upd.

To make sure that expected behaviour is *NOT* returning `NULL`s I looked into implementation of `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository` (specifically a class `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`) and found a following code regarding my case:

```
public List<T> findAllById(Iterable<ID> ids) {

    Assert.notNull(ids, "The given Iterable of Id's must not be null!");

    if (!ids.iterator().hasNext()) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    if (entityInformation.hasCompositeId()) {

        List<T> results = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (ID id : ids) {
            findById(id).ifPresent(results::add); // <--- here is what I meant above - we add only existing entities
        }

        return results;
    }

    ByIdsSpecification<T> specification = new ByIdsSpecification<T>(entityInformation);
    TypedQuery<T> query = getQuery(specification, Sort.unsorted());

    return query.setParameter(specification.parameter, ids).getResultList();
}
```

Comment: could someone with rep >= 1500 please create tag `spring-data-aerospike`?

Comment: What do you mean non existing entities? Are you passing a ID of an entity that does not exist? By design, findAll(ids) should be used when you have a list of existing entities IDs

Comment: @CrazySabbath  *"...By design, findAll(ids) should be used when you have a list of existing entities IDs..."*, where did you get this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was [fixed](https://github.com/aerospike/spring-data-aerospike/commit/b061e1a27a24ff07b1b59bb1b259712a71b1b8ff) in the latest snapshot.

As soon as smbdy from Aerospike team provides new release -- you can use it.
Until now you should filter nulls. That's frustrating, I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this normal behavior according to design? An excellent question and the answer depends on what you consider normal.

The findByIDs(...) method is ultimately implemented by the Aerospike "get(BatchPolicy policy, Key[] keys)". The method will return an array of Records ordered to match the order of the keys. If a record does not exist a null will be returned.

From an Aerospike perspective, the results are correct. But is it valid from a Spring Data perspective? How does Spring indicate that some records are not available for the set of requested IDs?

Comment: I suppose it shouldn't return `NULL`s in case entities with specified `ID`s do not exist. 

As a developer I had additional efforts for processing, because after retrieving results we have to add redundant logic to avoid `NPE`s.  Also it is confusing because a bunch of `NULL`s is hardly a explanatory result.
If we consider a `Repository` as a *pattern that isolates data access behind interface abstractions* we shouldn't rely on database specific things, we want to eliminate their impact.

I updated my question with an example how this case is handled for relational db repo.

Comment: Peter! Peter! Peter!

Comment: star67 makes a valid point and nulls should be filtered out. But the question remains how Spring Data indicates that there is no record for a specific IDs? If there is a specific Sprint Data pattern then it should be used.

Comment: @Helipilot50,  *how Spring Data indicates that there is no record for a specific IDs?*

I updated the question with implementation of the similar functionality for Spring Data JPA. As we can see, the pattern is the following: if entityManager returns NULL for ID then filter this out of resulting collection